# Is there a way to pass verified parameters to smart contract function in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, encryption-asymmetric, ether

I want to call a function named "testFunction" which takes "claimDate" as a parameter. claimDate parameter comes from a server via api.

```
contract TestSmartContract {

  testFunction(uint256 id, uint256 claimDate) public payable returns (uint) {
    // I need a logic to verify if claimDate is coming from a valid source which will mean it is correct.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can use signature verification to check if the data comes from the verified source.

The idea is that;

1. Let the source sign the `claimDate` from off-chain (ex. backend server).
2. Send the `claimDate` together with the signature to the contract.
3. The contract which stores source address verifies if the signature is correct. If yes, it means the `claimDate` is really from the source.

> ⚠️ Note that signing `claimDate` alone might not be enough. Because once the signature is created, it can be visible and reused by exploiters.

Read more: https://blog.chainsafe.io/how-to-verify-a-signed-message-in-solidity-6b3100277424

Comment: Thanks.
Here is another article that helped me understand the process.
https://medium.com/@PhABC/off-chain-whitelist-with-on-chain-verification-for-ethereum-smart-contracts-1563ca4b8f11

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wallet address to validate if the source is valid.

For example:

```
contract TestSmartContract {

   address sourceAddress = "0x00...";
    
   function testFunction(uint256 id, uint256 claimDate) public returns(uint) {
       require(msg.sender == sourceAddress, "Not valid source");
       //code to execute
   }
}
```

Comment: The issue is sourceAddress can pass the wrong claimDate. Also I do not have sourceAddress on contract level.

Comment: In this case, I don't know what kind of verification you want to do, it would be nice if you could explain the question better. The other answer that suggested using signature might also be valid depending on the case.